# Pandas Pivot Tables- Unexpected keyword 'cols'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, keyword-argument

I'm trying to make a pivot table using pd.pivot_table.

```
df1=df.pivot('Partner','Year','Value')
```

works no problem and produces a table

```
Year                        2011       2012       2013       2014
Partner                                                            
Albania                   0.000693   0.000663        NaN        NaN
Areas, nes                0.002310   0.014177   0.492017   0.633261 
Armenia                        NaN   0.000145        NaN        NaN
Belgium                   0.390415   0.400312   0.493444   0.643490
Brazil                    0.000231   0.000362   0.000518   0.000234
China                     0.024488   0.000443   0.000085   0.000052
Colombia                  0.425991   0.447333   0.488582   0.538809
```

However creating my_pivot;

```
def my_pivot(rows, values, aggfunc, plt=True):
    dfp = df
    piv = pivot_table(dfp, values=values, rows=rows, cols=cols,     aggfunc=aggfunc)
    print piv
    if plt: 
        plot(piv)
        show()


my_pivot(values = df['Value'], rows=df['Partner'], cols=df['Year'], aggfunc=np.sum,plt=True)
```

produces an error;

```
TypeError: my_pivot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cols'
```

I have no idea why this won't work, does anybody have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your function `my_pivot` does not have a "cols" argument - you need to add it. Also, the keyword arg for `pivot_table` should be "columns", not "cols" (see the call signature in the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html)).

Comment: you need to add 'cols' in your function my_pivot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html

Check this documentation of pandas pivot table function. There is no parameter named cols. There used to be 'cols' in older version of Pandas. Now, 'rows' is replaced by 'index' and 'cols' with 'columns'.

Try this:

```
def my_pivot(rows, values, aggfunc, plt=True):
    dfp = df
    piv = pivot_table(dfp, values=values, index=rows, columns=cols,     aggfunc=aggfunc)
    print piv
    if plt: 
        plot(piv)
        show()

my_pivot(values = df['Value'], rows=df['Partner'], cols=df['Year'], aggfunc=np.sum,plt=True)
```